# Cannot install TAP adapter driver on Windows 11 Virtual Machine

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tap, network-driver

I am trying to install a standalone vpn client on a Windows 11 ARM64 Virtual Machine that is runing on Parallels and MacBook Pro M1 chip.
I have tried to install many packages like [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) and [OpenVpn Connect for windows](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/) and some others and it always ends up failing installing TAP adapter driver.

I have no vpn clients installed and neither TAP adapter drivers installed on my system before installing all these clients.

I am trying to install it on a Parallels virtual machine, that is, Windows 11 x64.

Answer (score 0):

I use a UTM virtual machine with Windows 11 on my m1 macbook. Openvpn 2.5.6 for Windows ARM64 has been installed without any problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).